# Why does Facebook Graph API return error "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My iOS app was working perfectly with Facebook SDK until today I started to get this weird error:

```
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2;
        message = "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 500;
```

I am trying to do an FQL query and I haven't changed a single line of code. My access token is valid. Moreover, I went to Graph API Explorer, tried the exactly same FQL query from the Graph API Explorer (with the Application set to Graph API Explorer, and it worked. In Graph API Explorer, I've changed the Application to my app, and I got this error again, eliminating the possibility of the cause of my problem being the iOS SDK or access token. I've tried some of my other apps and they also work. The error seems to be bound to my app, but there is nothing wrong (or changed within a day, which used to work without a problem) with my app too in apps section. What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was probably a temporary issue. After writing the question, I tried the API call again, and it worked.